# String matching from a list

Tags: c#, string

I am making a web browser and I am stuck on this one thing. I want the addres bar to act as an address bar and a search bar. First I tried seeing if querying the search bar with `if adrBarTextBox.text.endswith(".com")` but immediately realized that not every domain ended with .com.

The code I am currently using (and are stuck with) is:

```
// Populate List.
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.suffix);
```

(`Properties.Settings.Default.suffix` is a list of every domain suffix currently available)

```
// Search for this element.
if (adrBarTextBox.Text.Contains(list.something????))
{
    // Do something (I have this part all set up)
}
```

The part i am having trouble with is

```
if (adrBarTextBox.Text.Contains(list.
```

I know it doesn't make sense but thats why i am asking. I have sat here thinking of a new way for hours and I am lost. I know that `.Text.Contains(list)` doesn't make sense and that's what I am stuck with.

I know the question is a bit noobish and there is probably some simple easy was staring me right in the face but hey. We all have to learn from somewhere.

Comment: 'I am making a web browser and i am stuck on this one thing.' - Just one thing?

Comment: Haha.. i have been stuck with a heap of things but this is the first one that i have really been stuck with to the point where i cant continue

Comment: @WilliamCustode There's always gonna be just one thing lol

Comment: "I am making a web browser"? Good luck with that one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need this

```
if (list.Any(x => adrBarTextBox.Text.Contains(x)))
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring) to determine if the input string is a valid URL.

If you want to match a string with words against another list of words, use

```
myList.Any(item => input.Contains(item));
```